# Why does DefaultAntiforgeryAdditionalDataProvider.GetAdditionalData() return an empty string?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net5

I'm debugging the Antiforgery code in the Asp.Net Core source code and found this:

[image]

Does anyone know what the purpose is of having a method that returns an empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is needed, because the [`IAntigorgeryAdditionalDataProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.antiforgery.iantiforgeryadditionaldataprovider.getadditionaldata?view=aspnetcore-2.1) interface requires it:

> Provides additional data to be stored for the antiforgery tokens generated during this request.

This is just the default (*or dummy*) implementation, which has no additonal data. If you want to transfer additional data, you need to create your own implementation and register it to the [ServiceCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0):

```
services.AddSingleton<IAntiforgeryAdditionalDataProvider, MyProvider>();
```